# Django serializer very slow takes 8-10 seconds

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

1. I'm trying to develop dashboard API which requires fetching data from several tables for each product, lets I have 5 products I need to query 5-6 other tables to get the data for each table.
2. Those 5 tables are very large table in future it might even reach to 1-2M records.(they are added every minute)
3. I used prefetch related for the backward relation - I agree query time gets reduced a lot, but serializer gets very slow no matter how many fields I have.
4. For dashboard I need to pick the latest record related to entities I'm displaying in dashboars.

My Model

Class Product():
name
Slug

Class ProductViewedByUser()// need last user who viewed the product
Users
Time

Similar to ProductViewedByUser I have 5-6 tables from which I need to fetch latest record.

I tried Prefetch Related query time is 115 ms for 3 products and nearly 500000 cached rows.

When I pass this to serializer no matter what fields are there even with one CharField- time goes to 3seconds

When I have multiple fields time goes to 10 seconds

I'm expecting serialization to be fast as possible.

Is it good idea to create one another table for storing latest records with respect to product

Comment: Probably the serializer is accessing a field somewhere that's not being prefetched. Do you have Django Debug Toolbar installed? How many queries does it say you're making?

Comment: Potentially a N+1 issue.

Comment: When I'm using SerializerMethodField to query, it gives me N+1 problem but with the number of products I need to show which is 4 as of now its comparatively faster. Like DB query is 79 and the time for that is 250ms. Total response time is 2.8seconds. @allexiusw

Comment: @NickODell when I don't explicitly mention field in serializer does that still call another query? Like I said when I even just pass large data and pick only 2 fields from that its still 8-10 seconds. Even N+1 query is not taking this much time.

Comment: It would depend on the serializer. There are definitely ways to access a field without explicitly mentioning it in the serializer.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code of the Serializer and the relations that you have to try to figure out how you can fix the issue? @Bharat

Comment: Query 
 ModelA.objects.select_related('country','state').prefetch_related('ModelBRelatedName','ModelCRelatedName','ModelDRelatedName','ModelERelatedName').filter(country__slug=country, state__slug=state).   Each of these prefetched objects are nearly 20k per ModelA. In Serializer I just want latest record from 20k.

Comment: This raises a question: if you only want the latest one, why not sort the queryset by date in descending order and take the first element? That would result in a much smaller result set sent back to Django.

Comment: I tried adding prefetch(queryset=Model.objects.order_by('created_at'),to_attr='var') there was no difference. I mean I did try to access the var[0] there was no speed improvement.